# nlp translation preserving emojis

Tags: python, translation, emoji, huggingface

Is there a way to prevent NLP translations from dropping emojis (or specific out of vocabulary tokens for that matter) when using the [huggingface--Helsinki-NLP--opus-mt-ROMANCE-en](https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-ROMANCE-en) models? Desired behavior:

"`Bonjour ma France` "@fr --> "`Hello my France` "@en

I can see the pre-trained default tokenizer knows of the emojis in its vocabulary, but looses it before decoding it. Sample code:

```py
from transformers import *

# setup
engine = 'pt'
resource = 'huggingface--Helsinki-NLP--opus-mt-ROMANCE-en'
nlp = pipeline(
   task="translation",
   model=MarianMTModel.from_pretrained(resource),
   tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(resource),
   framework=engine
)

# infer
translated = nlp.tokenizer.batch_decode(
   skip_special_tokens=True,
   sequences=nlp.model.generate(
      **nlp.tokenizer(
         text=["Bonjour ma France "],
         return_tensors=engine
      )
   )
)

# results
print(translated) # ['Hello, my France.']
print("" in nlp.tokenizer.get_vocab()) # True
```

Comment: Looking at the training data set, it seems like this model was not trained on phrases containing emoji. It's going to have a very hard time realizing that it should leave them alone. As an alternative, what if you removed the emoji before translating, then stuck the emoji back on after you're done translating?

Comment: Good observation. Before I go the non-trivial route of aligning removed emojis back into the translated form or transfer-learn with my emoji data, I noticed the tokenizer API can add [domain specific vocabularies](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/how-to-add-new-tokens-to-huggingface-transformers/). So, perhaps there is a reliable way to [hint the model](https://huggingface.co/blog/constrained-beam-search) to preserve these? Or maybe there's a bug somewhere or a lacking use-case feature?